# Failure in 1D std::vector boost serialization

Tags: serialization, boost, boost-mpi

I'm trying to serialize a `std::vector` as a member in the class, the attached code fails at throws segmentation fault that I've not been able to resolve this issue for weeks now. It's weird as it goes well in smaller size of container, but even this size is very small for memory issues.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/mpi/environment.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/communicator.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
#include <boost/version.hpp>
class Dummy
{
private:
    std::vector<unsigned int> array;
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class T> 
    inline void serialize(T & ar, const unsigned int /*version*/)
    {ar & array;}
public:
    Dummy()
    {};
    Dummy(const int nDivs) 
    {array.resize(nDivs);}
    ~Dummy() {}; 
};
int main(int argc, char* const argv[]) 
{
    boost::mpi::environment   env; 

    boost::mpi::communicator  world;

    boost::mpi::request req; 

    std::cout << "Using Boost "     
          << BOOST_VERSION / 100000     << "."  // major version
          << BOOST_VERSION / 100 % 1000 << "."  // minor version
          << BOOST_VERSION % 100                // patch level
          << std::endl;

    int MASTER = 0; 
    int tag    = 0;
    std::size_t size = 10000;  
    std::vector<unsigned int> neighbrs = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<Dummy> TobeSend (size, Dummy(2)); 
    std::vector<Dummy> TobeRecvd (size ,Dummy(1));

    for(auto itri:neighbrs)
    {
        int target = itri; 
        if(world.rank()!= target)
        {

            world.isend(target, tag, TobeSend);
            
        }
    }
    for(auto isource:neighbrs)
    {
        int source = isource;
        if(world.rank()!= source)
        {
            req= world.irecv(source, tag, TobeRecvd); 
            req.test(); 
        }
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

I'm building the code with:
`mpic++ -g mpidatatype.cpp -o output -lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization`
I've tried both version of 1.75 and 1.82. I'd appreciate help on this problem.

Here's the call stack as start of the program before sending occurs: [image]

Comment: If you are getting segmentation fault then it would be a good idea to show a call stack when it happens. Also you should specify compiler version and the way you run this executable.

Comment: Yeah. The code looks fine. It runs fine for me. Since you have different library versions check that you are actually finding the right versions at runtime. We need more information to be able to help with that. Versions, platform etc.

Comment: @sehe Thank you for comment. I'm in Ubuntu 22.04.2, and I've installed the latest version of boost -mpi in my machine, that's 1.82. And also it prints 1.82 as boost version; so I think it's finding the right version. What other information is needed? I've tried this code in so many ways including container to use boost_multi array or 2D vector or static array and all failed differently. One time, I'll get std::bad_alloc or std:::bad_length or segmentation fault; it's getting really annoying for me

Comment: I've tested in my personal machine (Ubuntu 20.04 and boost version of 1.71) and I got the same error. I can't understand this :(

Comment: "I've installed the latest version of boost-mpi" - how? Because the distro latest version is 1.74 https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libs/libboost-mpi1.74.0 - In general just expand the question with exact steps. All the symptoms you are reporting can be summarized to "Undefined Behaviour". This happens when you violate ODR or have ABI mismatch. You just have to trace down to the source and you can breathe again

Comment: @sehe I downloaded from here https://www.boost.org/users/download/ and then followed instructions https://kratos-wiki.cimne.upc.edu/index.php/How_to_compile_the_Boost_if_you_want_to_use_MPI to build with MPI support. I've debugged, but everything comes from behind the scenes, and it's not easy for me to see why and how it's failling

Comment: Using GDB, I know at least one processor won't be able to receive the message and then this weird error will be thrown that's really at the end of process

Comment: You could show us the backtrace. Even though "everything comes from behind the scenes" someone else might be able to something about it

Comment: @sehe I added call stack, is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes. It would be more informative if not truncated (because of the image). But at least now we know it's an allocation triggering the segv. Maybe you can mark the source line in main corresponding to that stack trace

Comment: @sehe finally, I found the answer, I added namespace `boost { namespace mpi {
      template<> struct is_mpi_datatype<Dummy>
        : public mpl::true_ { };
    } }` and the problem went away, but I had thought that this piece of code was optional, not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

So, I resolved this finally. The problem was missing

```
  namespace boost { namespace mpi {
      template<> struct is_mpi_datatype<Dummy>
        : public mpl::true_ { };
    } }
```

adding this line of code resolved my issue

Comment: Good find. My lack of MPI experience shows :)

Comment: @sehe Thanks a lot for brainstorming with me